# Why is the determinant of this matrix is zero?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to calculate the determinant of a matrix $M$ with floating-type coefficients. Why is the determinant of the following matrix evaluate to zero? Is it a problem related to the inexact arithmetic or because the matrix is too big?

```
M = {{1 + 0.008519508753585732` x, 0.` + 0.00017640606156269146` x, 
    0.` + 0.04530593870344164` x, 0.` + 0.17721470889868632` x, 
    0.` + 0.1319215277008768` x, 0.` - 0.0044790404983784836` x, 
    0.` + 0.025587792428499928` x, 0.` + 0.0006234381515854643` x, 
    0.` - 0.00011907209018292776` x, 0.` + 0.05770176295507422` x, 
    0.` + 0.09622951368933848` x, 0.` + 0.2464635776941779` x, 
    0.` - 0.0014565226982792934` x, 0.` + 0.18265276544228637` x, 
    0.` + 0.03364480342908203` x}, {-0.39266178638389015` x, 
    1 - 0.40100488887007013` x, 0.` + 0.04530593870344164` x, 
    0.` + 0.17721470889868632` x, 0.` + 0.1319215277008768` x, 
    0.` - 0.0044790404983784836` x, 0.` + 0.025587792428499928` x, 
    0.` + 0.0006234381515854643` x, 0.` - 0.00011907209018292776` x, 
    0.` + 0.05770176295507422` x, 0.` + 0.09622951368933848` x, 
    0.` + 0.2464635776941779` x, 0.` - 0.0014565226982792934` x, 
    0.` + 0.18265276544228637` x, 
    0.` + 0.03364480342908203` x}, {0.01578210745622432` x, 
    0.00017640606127450104` x, 1 + 0.03804335383943166` x, 
    0.` + 0.17721470889868632` x, 0.` + 0.1319215277008768` x, 
    0.` - 0.0044790404983784836` x, 0.` + 0.025587792428499928` x, 
    0.` + 0.0006234381515854643` x, 0.` - 0.00011907209018292776` x, 
    0.` + 0.05770176295507422` x, 0.` + 0.09622951368933848` x, 
    0.` + 0.2464635776941779` x, 0.` - 0.0014565226982792934` x, 
    0.` + 0.18265276544228637` x, 
    0.` + 0.03364480342908203` x}, {-0.006523983246557582` x, 
    0.0013162069955263214` x, -0.011354403825978313` x, 
    1 + 0.09470197352440768` x, 0.` + 0.1319215277008768` x, 
    0.` - 0.0044790404983784836` x, 0.` + 0.025587792428499928` x, 
    0.` + 0.0006234381515854643` x, 0.` - 0.00011907209018292776` x, 
    0.` + 0.05770176295507422` x, 0.` + 0.09622951368933848` x, 
    0.` + 0.2464635776941779` x, 0.` - 0.0014565226982792934` x, 
    0.` + 0.18265276544228637` x, 
    0.` + 0.03364480342908203` x}, {0.002285113142733098` x, 
    0.008852539814861657` x, -0.009955771186520065` x, \
-0.03475485501641121` x, 1 - 0.006429756828060157` x, 
    0.` - 0.0044790404983784836` x, 0.` + 0.025587792428499928` x, 
    0.` + 0.0006234381515854643` x, 0.` - 0.00011907209018292776` x, 
    0.` + 0.05770176295507422` x, 0.` + 0.09622951368933848` x, 
    0.` + 0.2464635776941779` x, 0.` - 0.0014565226982792934` x, 
    0.` + 0.18265276544228637` x, 
    0.` + 0.03364480342908203` x}, {0.057310713505067785` x, 
    0.055809437916312855` x, 0.195554441378524` x, 
    0.44700969773717336` x, -0.12148834137191358` x, 
    1 - 0.20703039476531815` x, 0.` + 0.025587792428499928` x, 
    0.` + 0.0006234381515854643` x, 0.` - 0.00011907209018292776` x, 
    0.` + 0.05770176295507422` x, 0.` + 0.09622951368933848` x, 
    0.` + 0.2464635776941779` x, 0.` - 0.0014565226982792934` x, 
    0.` + 0.18265276544228637` x, 
    0.` + 0.03364480342908203` x}, {0.02002100895838487` x, 
    0.022087251234364984` x, 0.1372824388809393` x, 
    0.36378925112173344` x, 
    0.031098966519449503` x, -0.127363515174603` x, 
    1 - 0.1631339969489123` x, 0.` + 0.0006234381515854643` x, 
    0.` - 0.00011907209018292776` x, 0.` + 0.05770176295507422` x, 
    0.` + 0.09622951368933848` x, 0.` + 0.2464635776941779` x, 
    0.` - 0.0014565226982792934` x, 0.` + 0.18265276544228637` x, 
    0.` + 0.03364480342908203` x}, {0.14239356271009448` x, 
    0.003591936811148119` x, 0.11007619365870613` x, 
    0.4229044738673411` x, 
    0.10074121081891027` x, -0.01510905855605537` x, \
-0.25601518374254006` x, 1 - 0.1254435773858274` x, 
    0.` - 0.00011907209018292776` x, 0.` + 0.05770176295507422` x, 
    0.` + 0.09622951368933848` x, 0.` + 0.2464635776941779` x, 
    0.` - 0.0014565226982792934` x, 0.` + 0.18265276544228637` x, 
    0.` + 
     0.03364480342908203` x}, {-0.348710050391641` x, \
-0.3101521273891286` x, 0.07444845623561583` x, 0.2862672161468376` x,
     0.17626610453184138` x, -0.03149252567590189` x, \
-0.012866328507941303` x, -0.12005401488576953` x, 
    1 - 0.13113963486263006` x, 0.` + 0.05770176295507422` x, 
    0.` + 0.09622951368933848` x, 0.` + 0.2464635776941779` x, 
    0.` - 0.0014565226982792934` x, 0.` + 0.18265276544228637` x, 
    0.` + 
     0.03364480342908203` x}, {-0.14122740345692156` x, \
-0.06913693377374074` x, -0.054816452715536965` x, \
-0.050317538416537355` x, 0.26674652565214674` x, 
    0.07913252795016454` x, -0.02047325675861597` x, 
    0.14845656014572256` x, 0.04685858719879823` x, 
    1 - 0.06566352683713467` x, 0.` + 0.09622951368933848` x, 
    0.` + 0.2464635776941779` x, 0.` - 0.0014565226982792934` x, 
    0.` + 0.18265276544228637` x, 
    0.` + 0.03364480342908203` x}, {0.000814235261042841` x, 
    0.06634981118987983` x, -0.02795954088222896` x, 
    0.03773430635898817` x, 0.17986725409297624` x, 
    0.038718315945623485` x, -0.03402807988411608` x, \
-0.016104381047763076` x, -0.0667632606858238` x, \
-0.0645130008241938` x, 1 - 0.00883076887651317` x, 
    0.` + 0.2464635776941779` x, 0.` - 0.0014565226982792934` x, 
    0.` + 0.18265276544228637` x, 
    0.` + 0.03364480342908203` x}, {0.03755684261958542` x, 
    0.01919748327822217` x, 0.022990285575479233` x, 
    0.054556044838387774` x, -0.03935844550256659` x, \
-0.01893787829431274` x, -0.03820748804897679` x, \
-0.03487148585626448` x, -0.014223069738585043` x, 
    0.002401005679414092` x, -0.02017353798366331` x, 
    1 + 0.1504006220284786` x, 0.` - 0.0014565226982792934` x, 
    0.` + 0.18265276544228637` x, 
    0.` + 
     0.03364480342908203` x}, {-0.017164150900606023` x, \
-0.006455198351985772` x, -0.0015560573781840878` x, 
    0.011997718705149513` x, 0.021698268802348625` x, 
    0.004390380029912595` x, 
    0.007753900878285473` x, -0.011267467773574968` x, \
-0.01666621906873395` x, -0.006395124703364272` x, \
-0.013118221216755627` x, 0.06048112959678273` x, 
    1 - 0.05306347660334788` x, 0.` + 0.18265276544228637` x, 
    0.` + 
     0.03364480342908203` x}, {-0.024268764391800986` x, \
-0.019050243920723506` x, -0.011823289432869033` x, \
-0.049754675992678826` x, -0.008370125100774173` x, 
    0.007477199839838825` x, 0.03869577747006689` x, 
    0.023212032474178166` x, 0.01929741477392748` x, 
    0.013617912441743249` x, 0.01872577127299216` x, 
    0.0049809035284877345` x, -0.0729102985261629` x, 
    1 + 0.1423879770406446` x, 0.` + 0.03364480342908203` x}, {0.`, 
    0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    1.`}};
Det[M]
```

I am trying to calculate the determinant of a matrix $M$ with floating-type coefficients. Why is the determinant of the following matrix evaluate to zero? Is it a problem related to the inexact arithmetic or because the matrix is too big?

Comment: `Det[Rationalize[M, 0]]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your assessment seems to be right. Taking the determinant with floating point `$MachinePrecision` produces terms with a relative magnitudes of around $10^{-900}$ which for all purposes is zero. However, these terms do cancel in the end and produce a non-zero determinant.

One way, is to just calculate numerically anyway.

```
nDet[xN_?NumericQ] := Det[M /. x -> xN]
Plot[nDet[n], {n, -7, 7}]
```

> [image: Numerical determinant evaluation]

However, we can acquire a good numerical approximation.
We do this easily by:

1. Replace the floating points numbers with fractions
2. Symbolically evaluate the determinant
3. Symbolically rework the result to a "nice" form
4. Convert this to floating point again for numerical calculations
5. profit

So we write:

```
sol=N[Det[Rationalize[M,0]]//ExpandAll]
```

and get

> 1. -0.72768659 x+0.095987832 x^2+0.028185109 x^3-0.0041976721 x^4-0.00086801627 x^5+0.000063110162 x^6+0.000020296871
>    x^7+3.0343132*10^-7 x^8+2.2144472*10^-8 x^9-7.7451027*10^-9
>    x^10-4.2592964*10^-11 x^11-3.1756552*10^-12 x^12+1.5042333*10^-13
>    x^13-8.8761349*10^-16 x^14

The [`ExpandAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpandAll.html)is necessary to get rid of these extreme fractions being produced .
The resulting approximation seems to work quite well for non "extreme" values of x. ($|x|<20\longrightarrow\epsilon<10^{-10}$)
As you can see by comparing it to the numerical evaluation:

```
LogPlot[Abs[nDet[x] - sol], {x, -200, 200}, PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> Full]
```

> [image: Absolute deviation of approximation to numerical solution]